# How to flex a 3D texture with OpenGL ES?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have tried to draw some 3D squares (with OpenGL on iPhone) and make them rotate around, now they look like a sphere.

http://i618.photobucket.com/albums/tt265/LoyalMoral/Post/ScreenShot2013-05-15at23249PM.png

But the square is flat (the first one on image below), and I want to flex it:

http://i618.photobucket.com/albums/tt265/LoyalMoral/Post/Untitled-1.jpg

someone told me that I have to use glsl, but I don't know shading language.

this is my vertex and fragment (follow Ray Wenderlich's tutorial):

```
// Vertex.glsl
attribute vec4 Position; 
attribute vec4 SourceColor; 

varying vec4 DestinationColor; 

uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Modelview;

attribute vec2 TexCoordIn;
varying vec2 TexCoordOut;

void main(void) { 
    DestinationColor = SourceColor; 
    gl_Position = Projection * Modelview * Position;
    TexCoordOut = TexCoordIn;
}


// Fragment.glsl

    varying lowp vec4 DestinationColor;

varying lowp vec2 TexCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Texture;

void main(void) {
     gl_FragColor = DestinationColor * texture2D(Texture, TexCoordOut);
}
```

could somebody help me? :)

Comment: The question if to use shaders or not is completely independent of your technique (though using shaders might help with implementing the geometric distortion on the GPU). What decides if you use shaders or not is the OpenGL ES version. But for your particular goal shaders alone won't suffice. Since ES neither has geometry shaders nor tessellation shaders, you need to first tessellate your quads into finer grids of multiple quads before you can do any geometric deformation on them (with which a vertex shader could then indeed help), since OpenGL can only draw flat primitives.

Comment: Search for mesh morphing libs in the web.There are plenty of ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a quad (pair of triangles) for a square use a grid for it. Thus you will be able to place vertices of the grid manually resulting in the shape you want.